# using idea to compile spring source code with 5.2.7-RELEASE can not find log4j and slf4j packages

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I use idea to build spring source engineering project,The project was successfully built as shown in the figure below.
[image]

When I create a main method and run it will include the following errors

```
Information:2021/2/12 21:23 - Build completed with 49 errors and 0 warnings in 2 s 284 ms
E:\idea_workspace\spring-framework-5.2.7.RELEASE\spring-jcl\src\main\java\org\apache\commons\logging\LogAdapter.java
Error:(22, 32) java: Package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
Error:(23, 32) java: Package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
Error:(24, 36) java: Package org.apache.logging.log4j.spi does not exist
Error:(25, 36) java: Package org.apache.logging.log4j.spi does not exist
Error:(26, 17) java: Package org.slf4j does not exist
Error:(27, 17) java: Package org.slf4j does not exist
Error:(28, 21) java: Package org.slf4j.spi does not exist
Error:(154, 38) java: Symbol not found
  Symbol:   class LoggerContext
  position: class org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.Log4jLog
```

Examples are as follows
[image]

What I am puzzled is that the log4j package actually exists in the project, and I don’t know what to do.I have recompiled several times and all have the same result, please help me to solve it, thank you!
The software version is as follows：

- spring: 5.2.7-RELEASE
- java: 1.8.0_161
- gradle: 5.6.4
- idea: 2020.1.1

Mainly caused by the log dependency of this module, but I don’t know what to do
[image]

Comment: Did you follow the [official guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/import-into-idea.md)? Why are you using such an old stand-alone version of Gradle when you should be using the wrapper?

Comment: This is the corresponding version officially recommended by spring5.2

Comment: You are right - I am a bit surprised have been stuck with that version for so long (they are on 6.8 now though).

Answer (score 0):

Just add required dependencies in your gradle file (sl4fj and log4j). When you use spring boot there is a starter and many dependencies into it, but when you use only Spring dependency it can ask another dependency for their work.

```
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '${version}'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '${version}'
```

Comment: On the surface it is so simple, but in fact it can’t be added. I caused it in the process of building the source code.